# Google Cloud functions Java 11 - How to Debug locally ? Avoid the need of re deploy with logs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using intellij IDE and maven project.

To debug cloud function, every time I need to Re-deploy with SYSO logs and taking 2 mins to upload.

Do we have any mechanism run JAVA GCP cloud functions locally so we can fast development and debug process ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run locally your function thank to the [Function Framework](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/first-java#building_and_testing_locally) and Maven

```
mvn function:run
```

This create a local webserver that listen on the port 8080. Curl it to test it

```
curl localhost:8080

curl -X POST -d "my data" localhost:8080
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, its working.

But 

What would be the syntax for RawBackgroundFunction ?

curl -X POST -d "{"name":"zzz"}" localhost:8080

after executing above command json is receiving as null

Comment: Hello Team,

Finally it worked : 

curl -X POST -d '{ "data" : { "data": "BASE64 encoded text" } }' localhost:8080

And thanks to Abhideep Chakravarty